# SOP Boolean expression of state variable and output of a Moore FSM

Tags: computer-architecture, logic, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I'm studying for an exam, but I don't have to hand in anything.</sub>

---

I have the state transition diagram of the FSM and its states encoding:

---

[image: state transition diagram]

---

I want to find the **sum-of-products** (SOP) Boolean expression of $S_0^1$, $S_1^1$ and output $y$. I've drawn tables for each next state, based on all current states ($S_0$ and $S_1$) and inputs ($A$ and $B$):

[image: tables]

After this, I don't have very clear how to proceed with drawing the output and state table truth / k-map to get the final Boolean expression.